# Mocking generic interfaces with Kotlin and Mockito

Tags: mocking, mockito, kotlin

I am trying to mock a generic interface in Kotlin using Mockito. But so far I have found no natural solution. Given:

```
interface X<T> {
    fun x(): T
}

fun f(x: X<Int>) = x.x()
```

I could mock `X` with any of the following:

1. `val x = f(Mockito.mock(X::class.java) as  X<Int>)`

   But that would generate an "unchecked cast" warning.
2. `@Mock lateinit var x: X<Int>`

   But I do not want to use the `@Mock` annotation because I like to have my fields final.
3. Introduce a helper function, as the [mockito-kotlin library](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) does:

   `inline fun <reified T : Any> mock(): T = Mockito.mock(T::class.java)!!`

   Then call it like this:

   `val x: X<Int> = mock()`

   But I do not want to use helper functions.

Is there an elegant pure Kotlin way to mock a generic interface with Mockito?
(I would prefer a version of 1. without the warning.)

Comment: Why don't you want to use helper functions? What is wrong with `val x = f(mock<X<Int>>())`?

Comment: Because it feels like a workaround for the "unchecked cast" issue. Is there a way to do it without a workaround?

Comment: I don't see [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) as a workaround to the "unchecked cast" issue. In fact, I see the "unchecked cast" issue as a (Java) workaround to not having reified type parameters (or something similar).

Comment: @mfulton26 After thinking this over, I absolutely agree with you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) project. This project contains all must have helpers for mockito. And supports mockito 2.1 as well.

Upd. To deal with "uncheked cast" use [Reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

You say that "But I do not want to use helper functions.", but why? This is inline function, so in compile time function will be inlined at all call sites will.

Comment: I do use that library, but this is not the issue here. I do want to know whether there is a way around the "unchecked cast" warning in a more direct way.

Comment: I think I see the point. It is not the problem of Kotlin but of the Mockito interface written Java which cannot express this. If Mockito would use reified type parameters, all would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library prevents indeed the need to suppress warnings if used correclty.

Here is an example. In the Maven `pom.xml` you import the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in your tests, you import the mock method:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.moc
```

Then you can comfortably mock whatever you need to mock:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    val sessionFactory: FactoryBean<SessionFactory> = mock()
    val eventDateReminderService: EventDateReminderService = mock()
    val eventDateService: EventDateService = mock()
    val templateService: TemplateService = mock()
    reminderService = ReminderService(sessionFactory, eventDateReminderService, eventDateService, templateService)
}
```

No need for casting or suppressing warnings. If you use the Mockito library directly, you will need to cast and suppress warnings.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use [Mockk](https://github.com/mockk/mockk) library.

It supports annotations, so to create a mock it's enough to write:

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class BookSpec {

  @MockK
  lateinit var author: Author
}
```

and then to record some behaviour:

```
every { author.name() } returns "Milosz Brzezinski"
```

or

```
every { author.rank() } throws OutOfScaleException()
```

Comment: Original question had "generic". Your sample hasn't